# how to view associated click function code

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, click

For example, i associate following function with some element

```
$('table#users tbody tr:first #save').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Now, if i don't know where this function is stored, is there a way to view associated with click() code? In above example, i want a way to view that in firebug, or in another way

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

If I'm writing in console following, i'm get a link to dom inspector

```
>>> ($('table#users tbody tr:first #save').click)
function()
```

but link is for jquery library, not the code i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will answer your question [How to find event listeners on a DOM node when debugging or from the JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node/447106#447106)

The reason you get a link to the DOM inspector on the code you wrote is because calling `$(selector).click` will actually raise the click events and return the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Try the eventbug plugin for Firebug: http://blog.getfirebug.com/2009/10/30/event-listener-view-for-firebug/

Answer (score 1):

There is also default method of Function object in javascript - toSource

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/function_object.html

example:

> > > >>> $('.jq-runCode').click.toSource()
> > >
> > > "(function (d) {return d ? this.bind(b, d) : this.trigger(b);})"